# Properties pie chart of external hard drive does not update

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem

I have an LaCie external hard drive which is 1TB big. I use it mostly for backups but lately I have found that it 'lies' about the size available.

This is a screenshot of the properties dialog
[image: properties]

When I delete something from the hard drive, the number after Contents (662.4GB) changes but the number after Free space (72.0GB) doesn't. No matter what I do, the used and free number don't change and I keep having only 72.0GB available which is, exusez le mot, bullshit.

Comment: What is the output of `df -h`

Comment: Appearantly I needed to clean my thrash can before the files were really gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to empty my thrash can before the files were really deleted from the hard drive